# Do you understand it when you hear the word "continued customer?”

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Assume you are now taking a look at a customer registration sheet with a check item saying "New Customer / Continued Customer." Do you find the word "Continued Customer" just natural English? As far as I'm concerned, "existing customer" is more common.

Comment: 'Continued customer' does not sound natural at all. I agree about 'existing customer'

Comment: Takashi, feel free to write a self answer to this question.

Comment: We thank our _existing customers_ for their _continued support_.

Comment: Or "repeat customer" or "return customer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Continued customer' doesn't make any sense. 'Continued *custom*' certainly does, because if someone regularly does business with you, their custom is continuous. It would not be unusual for a business to say "thank you for your continued custom" to a regular client.

'Existing customer' is a term you would use to differentiate from someone who may be a *new* or *potential* customer.

'Regular customer' would describe someone with whom you do business frequently.